# Is there a way to update the tkinter messageboxes live?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI(using tkinter) for checking the code using test cases. Just like you see in Competitive Programming Websites like Hackerrank , SPOJ , CodeForces etc.

Now I have somehow managed to print in the terminal for what test cases the code failed and for what the code passed.

But the catch is , I want to do the same in tkinter messageboxes.

My code runs in loop , so it checks each and every test cases and then prints out the result immediately rather than storing all the result in a list and checking them in the end.

So I want my Messagebox to also do the same i.e update everytime a test cases has been evaluated and show whether the test case was passed or not?

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Umm.. From what I could understand here, my question is if the `messagebox` gets updated constantly with info based on passing or failing the test cases, how is a user supposed to read all that ? Or did I miss some point in your question?

Comment: I mean like : First the Message box pops up and shows : Running Test Case 1 , and then after verifying the solutions , the same Message box should show  : Passed Test Case 1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Novel suggested in his answer to create your own `messagebox` inheriting from `tk.Toplevel`, Here is a (Not the best) working solution which will serve the purpose that you described.

It inherits from `tk.Toplevel` class.

## Documentation of my messagebox :D

I implemented a method called `updateInfo()` which can be simply used to update the message and also the title of the window.

Note that the size of window, fonts, colors are always customizable so feel free to add your touch.
Here is the implementation:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyCrazyBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title='', message=''):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('400x200+200+100') # Must change these accordingly
        self.title(title)
        # set the options according to your needs.
        self.messageLabel = tk.Label(self, text=message,
                                     bg='#fff', fg='#000', font=('roboto', 25))
        self.messageLabel.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def updateInfo(self, title='', message=''):
        self.title(title)
        self.messageLabel.configure(text=message)


# To create a new message box just create an instance of the class MyCrazyBox
```

Both the `title` and `message` default to `''` - an empty string - if not provided when creating am `instance`.

All these below examples will work to create a `messagebox` from class `MyCrazyBox`.

```
# 1. MyCrazyBox('Info', 'Loading....') # both title and message provided
# 2. MyCrazyBox(title='test', message='Just a check') 
# 3. BoxVariable = MyCrazyBox('warning', 'Wrong credentials')
# 4. MyCrazyBox('Just the title')
# 5. MyCrazyBox(message='Where is the title, you freak?')
```

Once you have created a box, you can use that same box to update info as many times as needed with the `.updateInfo()` method.

**Important::** You need to `assign` the `MyCrazyBox` instance to a `variable` if you want to use `.updateInfo()` method.

like

```
aBox = MyCrazyBox('Info', 'Loading....')
root.after(4000, lambda: aBox.updateInfo('Info', 'Still Running the test case'))
root.after(5554, lambda: aBox.updateInfo('Congrats', 'Test case Passed'))
# added delay to simulate some process happening
```

Simply said
`aBox.updateInfo('Test', 'Just checking')` will update the box with the arguments supplied. The `argument` nature is the same as `class instance` creation.

## Complete example

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyCrazyBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, title='', message=''):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('400x200+200+100') # Must change these accordingly
        self.title(title)
        # set the options according to your needs.
        self.messageLabel = tk.Label(self, text=message,
                                     bg='#fff', fg='#000', font=('roboto', 25))
        self.messageLabel.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def updateInfo(self, title='', message=''):
        self.title(title)
        self.messageLabel.configure(text=message)
        
def dosomething():
    aBox = MyCrazyBox('Info', 'Running test case 1..')
    root.after(5000, lambda: aBox.updateInfo('Congrats', 'Test case 1 Passed.'))
    # just to simulate a delay of 5 sec in checking test case
    
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Do something', command=dosomething).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mhmmm may i ask, what about the icons and sound effects? and the flashing effect?

Comment: @CoolCloud Hell No :D . As I said this is not even a good solution, it just shows the info to the user (which I strongly believe is most important - someone running their test cases on a judge system won't care about those effects unless heavily required). Even though I'm pretty sure this should work for the OP's needs, This is definitely not a good solution for someone looking for exact fancy implementation of `tkinter.messagebox`.

Comment: @PSSolanki I recommand to rename that method sinces its a basic widget method. I think otherwise its a bad advice. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method

Comment: @Atlas435 Yes, true, might cause confusion, maybe name it something like `update_messagebox()` or something

Comment: @Atlas435 That's right. I actually had a different name when I wrote it first up. I changed it to `.update()` and it worked. But that still might cause ambiguities so edited. Even though I will edit and change the name of method, a quick question, shouldn't defining a method `.update()`, override the existing `.update()` method for that widget or is there any point I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the messagebox module that comes with tkinter, then no. But you can easily make your own message boxes with the `Toplevel` widget, and those can do anything you want.